# How can I apply a status (condition) check direct to a model in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have added a status column to my product table. Now I want that when I use `Product::all()` I get only the product with status is active. something like soft delete. I want that the model ignores the products that are passive until they are activated again. Is there a way to do this?

PS: I already used the model (Product::class) in tons of places. so i am looking a direct way that affects all the methods i made already. otherwise i will have to apply the solution to all the methods one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for exactly the same functionality as Soft Deletes, you can use [global scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#query-scopes). [`SoftDeletes` trait uses global scope](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.3/Eloquent/SoftDeletes.php#L21). So, if you'll apply global scope to `Product` model `Product::all()` will return all results where `status = 1`.

Comment: Yes that seems to be what i was looking for. I will try the global scope stuff.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way IMO, create a scope in the model

```
function scopeActive($query) {
  return $query->where('status', 1);
}
```

This way, you could do something like this

```
Product::active();
```

Comment: i am looking for a solution that affects all the methods i already made. this way i have to go trough all the methods and add one by one.

Comment: In this case, you could add all as a static method in the model. I am not sure if its the best way to go though. Note that it will throw an error if you dont pass the array argument.

public static function all($ar = [])
    {
        return self::where(['status_id'=>1])->get();

    }

Answer (score 1):

You can try it as:

```
 Product::where('status', 1)->get()
```

Comment: i am looking for a solution that affects all the methods i already made. this way i have to go trough all the methods and add one by one.